# Uncaught TypeError:Object[object object] has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scrollable

I m going to try this: http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html
But without **any event trigger**, I m getting below error

[image]

But I have confusion about, why the **on** method not finding in even **page load**

```
<head>
<link href="css/scrollable-horizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/scrollable-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Nothing done at **javascript part**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // initialize scrollable
  $(".scrollable").scrollable();
});
</script>
```

It stopped my further implementation. Have any idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery .on method was added in 1.7.  You need to update your JQuery as from your screenshot you are currently using 1.6

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Once downloaded from [here](http://jquery.com/download/), change the below where marked

```
<head>
<link href="css/scrollable-horizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/scrollable-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> <!-- Change this line -->
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery 1.6.1 - [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) didn't exist back then (not until 1.7).

Your options:

- Either you use [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead.
- Or you update to the latest jQuery.

In regard to the second option, replace

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update jQuery version.

Because jQuery 1.6 does not have `.on()` it's added into new version of jQuery.