# I get this message "Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I get this message:

> "Object [object Object] has no method 'on' "

to the code:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    self.setDimensions();
});
```

what can I do?
I already have jQuery 1.9...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912346/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519177/uncaught-typeerrorobjectobject-object-has-no-method-on

Comment: And is it the right version?  `on` is 1.7 and later.

Comment: @JasonSperske - If he didn't include jQuery then the error would say `$ is not defined`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 good point, I think all signs point to an outdated jQuery library

Comment: It is also possible that something is overwriting `$`

Comment: Or that something is overwriting `$.fn.on`, though not likely.

Comment: @KevinB - That's [true](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bP3Cb/).

Comment: @user: Need more info. All you've done is shown use that you're trying to use the `.on` method, and it doesn't work. Clearly the cause is elsewhere.

Comment: Try to log $.fn.jquery just before the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use at least jQuery version 1.7

Prior to 1.7, you can replace `.on()` with `.bind()` (if you're not using event delegation).

The best would probably be for you to upgrade to the lastest jQuery version - 1.9 ATM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the latest version of jQuery, and it still says there is no `on`, then that means [some other library is overwriting `$`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bP3Cb/). To solve this issue, try this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Use $ here
    var self = mysterious();
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        self.setDimensions();
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/SUBGD/